# Display custom page when error happens in Koa

Tags: error-handling, koa, koa2

Here is the background of the question : I'm following the [kick-off-koa](https://github.com/koajs/kick-off-koa) using **Koa 2**. But the exercises in the kick-off are designed for Koa 1. I've created an issue for this problem of Koa 2 : [Task of error handler with Koa 2 cannot pass](https://github.com/koajs/kick-off-koa/issues/36).

For short, my problem is how to display a custom error page when a 500 error happens.

Here are the codes :

```
// error handler middleware
function errorHandler(ctx, next) {
  try {
   return next();
  }
  catch(err) {
    ctx.status = err.status || 500;
    // I would like to display the custom message as follows     
    ctx.body = 'Oops! internal server error';   
    // with emitting the error event, don't work
    // ctx.app.emit('error', err, ctx);      
  }
}

// to generate error
app.use(router.get('/error', ctx => {
  ctx.throw('oops', 500);
}));
```

But my page of error is always displaying as "Internal Server Error", which is  the default message. It seems that `ctx.body = 'Oops! internal server error';` couldn't modify the page.

Thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Koa2, you don't have to return inside middleware, instead, use `await`. And by the way, your middleware function **MUST** be an `async` function.

Here is an example of a combined 404 and 500 middleware:

```js
  app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    try {
      await next()

      if (ctx.status === 404) ctx.throw(404)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
      ctx.status = err.status || 500
      ctx.body = errorPage.render({ // Use your render method
        error: err,
      })
    }
  })

  // Your normal routes here
```

First, Koa awaits for the next middleware in the chain (which is your normal routes). If nothing is found or an error occurred, the middleware chain goes backwards and the next line is executed, which throws a `404` and its captured inside the `catch`.

Now in the catch statement, you can get either `404`, `500` (by default) or `5xx` if other error occurred.

The body of the page is also set with a render of your template and passing the error to the template so you can make use of it.

You don't have to emit the error as this is the last catch in the chain.

Comment: Sanz, would you like to tell me if i want to send the response just in the code , then what i have to do ? I would like to thank you if you answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085204/what-is-the-replacement-of-expresss-res-send-user-xyz-or-res-end-in