# What is the replacement of express's res.send({ user: 'xyz' }); or res.end() in koa?

Tags: node.js, koa

I want to send the `response` with an `error` in my koa app when there is no `sessionId`.I explored But didn't get anything helpful for me to do the same. I also used `return ctx.throw(401);` for `unauthorized` but it is not good, `ctx.throw(401);` just sending the "unauthorized", I want to add some specific information and after adding just send the response to the client. 
can anyone suggest me what to do the same?

My code is:

```
index.validateKey = async (ctx, next) => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var authorized = ctx.headers.sessionid ? true : false;
        if (!authorized) {
             return ctx.throw(401); //HERE , I want to send .
        }
        resolve();
    });
    await next();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using async await when there is no async call?

Answer (score 0):

You can check sessionId in sync so no async await function is needed. 
Your middleware function can be like this.

```
async(ctx, next) => {
    var authorized = ctx.headers.sessionid ? true : false;
    if (!authorized) {
        return ctx.throw('session Id required', 401);; 
        /*HERE , You can send custom message and return.*/
    }
    /* call next middleware else*/
    await next();
})
```

Comment: Thanks Chetan, But can i send the object in ctx.thwor() ?

Comment: koa js uses https://github.com/jshttp/http-errors to generate errors which clearly states **message - the traditional error message, which should be kept short and all single line** so you have two options here, you can stringify object and send as same in above method. or `ctx.throw(401,'errorstring', { error: 'object' });` then catch error object in single try catch of koa and take action accordingly.